# How use a postgres database as if it were native to Rails

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to the rails world and I need to use an existing database for a rails project, for example I have a "games" table that does not have the columns created_at and updated_at, if I add them in the postgres terminal, rails would recognize my tables as objects ("Game" for example)? or should I generate the model for each table in my database? what would be the correct way to fetch all tables like a objects and use them from the controllers?

Comment: Search for "rails reverse engineering postgres"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, one version is to use some kind of reverse engineering gem that would automatically generate models for your database tables with all the associations, foreign keys etc.

BUT if you are new to Rails, I would definitely suggest doing that by hand for a couple of reasons:

1. Those gems will not understand namespacing (a solid guess of mine) e.g. If you have a `admin_users`, `admin_other_table`, `admin_suggestions` tables, the most reasonable class name in ruby would be `Admin::User`, `Admin::OtherTable`, `Admin::Suggestion`, but there is no way that these gems would understand that.
2. If it makes more sense to name your model different than the table (and then map the correct table with `self.table_name=`, gems won't help.
3. If associations need to be defined only one way then your models will get a lot of code in them that is just useless( if you have "user has many articles with a foreign key of `author_id`" maybe you don't need the `user.articles` method, but your going to get it anyways.

Probably there are a lot more of these cases. So I would strongly suggest doing it by hand so you have full control of what kind of code is written.